# IOS google images search

Tags: ios, swift

I want to develop IOS app so I can search images from google and display it on app but i had hard time to to find api is there any way to send request to  and get images from google and thank you.

Comment: Type "google image search api" in to a search engine.

Comment: https://github.com/lukegeiger/googleimageapi Try this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be limited. We encourage you to use the Custom Search API, which now supports image search.

Comment: Is it legal to use images gathered from that API inside the app?